# On Debian in fluxbox, GtkPod has no write permission, but does in GNOME

Tags: debian, gnome, mount, ipod, gtkpod

In fluxbox I manually mount my iPod, then run GtkPod as a normal user, unfortunately this doesn't give me write permissions as a normal user.
(I can paste the error message in later when I am home if needs be, but it's a generic "Unable to write to /drive, permission denied")
In GNOME however the iPod is automatically mounted and the normal user has write permissions.

Please can someone explain how GNOME is mounting it so that write permission is enabled for normal user?

Comment: Have you tried running it with `sudo` just to see if it works?

Comment: What is the command you use to mount?

Comment: @MaxMackie I do not wish to add myself to sudo'ers. However I did try as root, and as root GtkPod does not even recognize that there is an iPod device connected

Comment: @enzotib mount /dev/sdb2 /media/ipod

Answer (score 1):

Examine the permissions of the drive after mounting it using `ls -ld /drive` (or better yet, `stat /drive`). When you mount as root, it's probably getting mounted with root ownership (maybe with reading privileges for other users). You might want to mount with `-o uid=[[your UID]]`.

The way GNOME mounts is (nowadays) using `gvfs-mount` - this uses an assortment of Unix tricks to have everything work without using `sudo`, and - among other things - gives you write-permissions to the files. (This used to be done with `gnome-mount` or `pmount`, but it seems that `gvfs-mount` is the latest incarnation).

Comment: Thank you, I was unaware of the -o switch and hadn't thought that such a thing might exist, which seems very stupid now.
This will no doubt be the solution to my problem, can't be sure though until I am home to test. Will update.